# ¿Porque me permite poner un callback incorrecto?

Tags: typescript

Estoy definiendo una función que recibe un `callback` el cual le especifico que debe contener un parametro necesariamente.

```
const myFunction = (fetch: ( data:string ) => Promise<any>) => { ... }
```

Defino una función que no requiere parámetros y en teoría esto debería marcar un error.

```
const promiseTest = () => new Promise(...);
```

utilizo `myFunction` pero no me detecta ningún error

```
const result = myFunction(promiseTest);
```

### Cuando si marca error

lo interesante es que si hago el mismo ejemplo pero definiendo un parámetro incorrecto en `promiseTest` Ahí si detecta el error, ejemplo de como si marca error

```
const promiseTest = (data:number) => new Promise(...)
```

Todo esto lo probé igualmente en [typeScript.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0+mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS+ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCMpoiDwADEuLB6o0eaAlUjUBp8lPuHUGPOqZROMx+IM2PPOOxENJvjqeQA+OhsRBCSAAHjMeGPR+5p4A3ooSiV+1d2NILzReQxjuYC5LvOt4Ps+r5vpBMpypACrwMqkY1kyViCF+UJRvwi55jqADcEGQSUM4aEqkYMNAzDwJG-AAEy4fhoAAL54ZBTioPiXiod+8h4Ux5KNFS8znpeOD6L+U5gaAL4sTm7H9PGZ5IJeSoEnK3qPpJ9GQZmqA4FCkAcKgSpKhJUkEWZKnQHoJH1JAjIYNwKD6Bs4gKGQF6cAw3CUXRZklAxNEAAxBT5b4MXRDHSvxNAElEYmDiO5jjpwSoEEJmYiVSdGRZSNCpYp6WidRk5Klhy67vuh4nhp0lsSackSApF6Zsp+iqSg6mmWZ2m6cgBlGSZmm+RZVmRjZdlwo5gjOWg3zuZ53nMb5-mgNRQUBSFfnhXxOUlvosVFby8WjklKVpZAGWoLReGKEAA)

Comment: En typescript, es válido asignarle a cualquier `callback` una función que tenga menos parámetros que la definición del tipo (o incluso ningún parámetro). Lo que si no puedes es pasas más parámetros, o pasar menos en el orden incorrecto.

Comment: Por ejemplo, para  un tipo `(data: string, otro: number) => Promise<any>` sería válido el callback sin argumentos, `() => new Promise(...);`, pero también es válido `( data:string ) => Promise<any>)`, y por supuesto que también el idéntico  `(data: string, otro: number) => Promise<any>`

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Entonces no significa que este haciendo algo mal.
Existe alguna manera de hacer que si marque error, si no lleva los parámetros?, me interesa expresar que sean necesarios los parámetros

Comment: No @Richard, no estás haciendo nada mal, es así como funciona. Acepta los parámetros definidos o menos respetando el orden y el tipo como te expliqué. La verdad no sabría decirte con absoluta certeza si es posible hacer lo que quieres, pero estoy casi seguro que no. Esperemos a ver si alguien conoce algún truco para lograrlo.

Comment: Si lo piensas, tiene sentido. No tienes por qué obligar al callback a consumir los argumentos que le pasas, el callback es algo externo. Tú puedes informarle los tipos con los que lo vas a llamar en la firma del método, pero si utiliza o no los argumentos que tu le das de manera interna, no es responsabilidad de quien lo invoca. Lo que te importa a ti donde se consuma es que el tipo de retorno sea el que se especifica.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Pensándolo un poco de esa manera, tiene sentido y creo que podría manejar de manera diferente si dicho callback no permite mis argumentos. Por lo tanto ahora empezare a verificar que tipo de errores puedo manejar ahí.

Comment: ¿Porqué dices que el `callback` es incorrecto? No hay forma que Typescript pueda **verificar** la firma de la función `callback` que pasas a tu método, ya que es una característica de JavaScript que no puede ser modificada por Typescript. Podrías hacer una verificación manual, o declarar un tipo para tu `callback` y asegurarte que la función  la definas usando dicho tipo, sin embargo, aún así, no hay un `guard` que te obligue a definir la función con esos argumentos aunque la declares del tipo personalizado. Recuerda que Typescript está pensado para facilitar las cosas en tiempo de desarrollo.